# Android detect screen edge gestures from any application

Tags: android, view, filter, touch

I am trying to make an app that detects gestures swiped from the edge of the screen in any application, similar to swipepad or smart statusbar.

I have tried to make a view with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW but it either filters all touches events or doesn't receive any depending on the NOT_TOUCHABLE flag.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up sticking with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW but setting it extremely small on the edge of the screen